# What is a free option to create a 3D animation of my logo?

Tags: logo, software-recommendation, animation

I'm looking for a software, online or downloadable, which can animate my logo, which I will put in my YouTube channel. I want the animation to be 3D, and free. There should also be no watermarks, or branding on it.

Comment: "Animate my logo" can mean a lot of things, so it's not clear what you are trying to do. Please edit your question to explain what you've already tried and what effort you've made. We can't help you if you're not willing to try things and work on your own. No one here is likely willing to work for free for you either out of the goodness of their heart.

Comment: @Scribblemacher I think OP is after what a lot of content creators call an 'intro', basically a short animated version of their youtube handle, often used before or after the video starts.

Answer (score 3):

The application you are most likely looking for is [Blender](https://www.blender.org/), its free and has its own [stackexchange site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). So support available.

This said it might take you a while to get your logo animated in the way you want. Animation and learning animation is a bit tedious at first, good general skill to have; Well worth the investment.

Remember whatever you choose: Start simple! If not then chances are you will never get it done.

Comment: Yep, I know about Blender. I am trying to do it, but it is very hard to do it the way I like. But I'm still working on it!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the good comments already given, let me give you a software recommendation, for the intro animation (I think that's what you're after)"

Adobe After Effects. There are a lot of free to use or cheap animated logo's to find for AE. Give 'After Effects Free Template' a go and you'll find a whole lot.

If you don't have the funds to invest in the software I would suggest downloading the free trial to create the intro.